# How do Elixir with Mix make a daemon?

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, reltool

Elixir & Mix all want to make the server as a daemon.
There have not been able to find the right way.

In addition, I want to use the erlang reltool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `--detached` option to start the runtime system detached from the system console. It is meant to be used for running daemons and backgrounds processes:

```
elixir --detached -S mix run
```

Regarding reltool, you can use [exrm](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm) although and pass `-detached` (single `-`) when configuring the VM arguments. The full argument list for the runtime system can be found here: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

Comment: You don't need to pass `-detached` with exrm, since running your release with `bin/myapp start` automatically runs it in detached mode.

Comment: but what if the host server get rebooted? Would my elixir app start automatically again? Or do I have to start it manually?

Comment: @simo, you can use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/running.html) to ensure that the process is started on reboot

Answer (score 2):

You should use `--erl "-detached"` since Elixir 1.9+. Like this:

```
MIX_ENV=prod elixir --erl "-detached" -S mix run --no-halt
```

or for Phoenix:

```
MIX_ENV=prod elixir --erl "-detached" -S mix phx.server
```

Comment: where do logs go using these commands?